# "SecurityError: The operation is insecure." when trying to include JS file

Tags: javascript, ssl, vue.js

I have a remote HTTPS-server on which I published my website.
This site is being displayed in Chrome as it should, but in Firefox or IE it is not.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I got a security error in my console. I have googled this problem, but still have no correct answer. Maybe someone here has encountered a problem like this. I'd be very appreciative if someone helped me to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Please add more information: for example, the source code that is throwing the error would be super valuable. Otherwise, I doubt we'd be able to help.

Comment: @Dexter if I open my website in `http://`, not `https://` it's alright, no errors occurred. My server uses ssl-sertification

Comment: If you're serving content over SSL, everything needs to be over ssl. Your app is trying to serve something over http instead when the site is requested as https. To resolve, use relative urls.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to your `vendor.js`. It is auto-builded script and it contains all the code from the `Vue components`.

As **@KevinB** said, inside the generated file `vendor.js` your code probably deals with `http://website.com` link. So you gotta check out your `Vue components` on such links and change them to SSL-certificated.

Wish it helps.